# How NOT to merge into a single post images uploaded consecutively on the Facebook wall

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-wall

When uploading consecutive pictures on the Facebook wall, they are merged into a single post. However, in my case, those images are handwritten post (generated using an iPhone app), so we definitely don't want them to be merged into a single post.

How can I make sure than each picture is display within its own individual post on the Facebook wall ?

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: upload them to different albums, there will be one post per album on the wall

Comment: That could work, you should add it as an answer. I wish I could just send them to the "Wall Photos" album thought...